# Error while building Glibc 2.25 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, glibc, libc

I'm trying to build Glibc 2.25 on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine and using the build instructions given here : https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds#Building_glibc_with_intent_to_install

I'm getting this error when running the `make` command :

```
make: libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by make)
```

What could this error possibly mean ?

Comment: It means that the `make` binary you are running was compiled with GNU libc 2.27, but you are trying to invoke it with an older version of GNU libc.  GNU libc is only _backward_ compatible (that is, if you compile programs with an older version they should work when run with a newer version).  It is not _foward_ compatible (if you compile programs with a newer version, it probably won't work if run with an older version).

Comment: Most likely somehow during your process you have reset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar to point to the older version of GNU libc (2.25) that you are compiling; once you do that no programs built with the newer version will run anymore.  It's impossible to say more than that with the information provided here.

Comment: It was actually a problem with VmWare. I tried building it with VirtualBox and it worked. I'm not really sure why does that happen.